# Slow search results

Tags: catalogsearch, magento1.9.2.3

To search for products I'm using doofinder and I can see search results immediately inside a popup and that's fine but then if press enter must wait a few seconds up to a minute until all the products being displayed on Magento search results page. It seems like Magento ignore the results from doofinder and when enter is pressed it runs search query. Any ideas why it does it so slow ?
Of course if there is only a two or three items found is quicker but in case if there is more this process is very very slow.
(Standard Magento search).

I did some research in the meantime but what I found is actually very old, most of the articles I found were dated 3/4 years ago and referring to Magento up to  1.7 so actually useless in this case.